# How do I position the Y-axis with the zero above the base of the graph?

Tags: core-plot

**Scenario:** a line/scatter graph with some negative & positive values.

**Problem:** The negative values are beyond the base of the graph.

**Desire:** To see ALL values with the visible graph area.

I need to adjust the Y-axis' zero/negative values upward to display ALL of the graph.

There must be a simple way to do this... via range?

Ric.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `yRange` of the plot space. Plot ranges are defined by a starting location (e.g., -10) and a length (e.g., 25). This example range would start at -10 and extend to 15 (-10 + 25).